# How can I echo ( php for loop variables ) in html table?

Tags: php, html, css

```
for ($q = 1 ; $q < 7 ; $q++ )
{
echo $q ; echo $row;
}
```

now this code works fine but i want to echo 2 rows like in the image below:

[image: the $row is a string value from sql]
 I don't want use other for loop, 
Can i do it with table html tags ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using variables that you will `echo` later just like this:

```php
$tableHeader = "";
$tableRow = "";

for ($q = 1 ; $q < 7 ; $q++ )
{
    $tableHeader .= "<th>" . $q . "</th>";
    $tableRow .= "<td>". $row ."</td>";
}

echo "<table> <tr>$tableHeader</tr> <tr>$tableRow</tr> </table>";
```

Comment: Thanks,, can I use table tag to echo inside it because i have other for loops every loop start from different values ?

Comment: @Aiman Yes of course just remove it from my echo and append to your final 'html table string'. Don't forget to validate the answer and `upvote` it if it was helpfull :)

Comment: Thanks it's working, and i upvoted your answer, but get logic error when I add -1 after $q ```$q-1``` to echo 1 , 2 , 3, etc.

Comment: In SO you can use the **V** icon under the 2 arrows to downote or upvote. This icon mark the answer has the correct answer of your question. It's help other user to directly see what the answer is.

Comment: your code is perfect but how can I echo the result of ```$q-1```without get the logic error ?

Comment: @Aiman How can I answer your question? Have you code to share ? Where do you call your `$q-1` ?

Comment: here```$tableHeader .= "<th>" . $q-1 . "</th>";```